# Regex to extract Address from js code

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to extract an address from js code.

I have the following line extracted from raw javascript.

```
(new GLatLng(45.512242,-73.554009),'2860 Main Street S',icon_near)
```

I've made this Regex

```
"\(new\sGLatLng\(           #Start of the match
(?<Lat>\-?\d{1,3}.\d+)      #Latitude
,
(?<Long>\-?\d{1,3}.\d+)\)   #Longitude   
,'
(?<Address>.+)              #The address
(?=',icon_near\))           #Positive LookAhead. The regex end just before ',icon_near)"
```

The problem is that I have multiple addresses together, and the regex match don't stop until the last `,icon_near\)` is found.

---

I resolved my issue with this regex:

```
,
'(?<Address>.+?)'
(?=,icon_near\))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
\(new\sGLatLng\(          #Start of the match
(?<Lat>\-?\d{1,3}.\d+)    #Latitude
,
(?<Long>\-?\d{1,3}.\d+)\) #Longitude   
,
'(?<Address>.+)'          #The address
(?=,icon_near\))          #Positive LookAhead. The regex end just before ',icon_near)
```

The single quotes were misplaced. Moreover, I remove one non needed single quote.

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/sX8dB2